# Soundcloud javascript api in Mobile App facing troubles

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, soundcloud

I have created a player using Sencha Touch latest version and integrate the Soundcloud. The app is working well on the web browser because I'm runing the app on local server (Wamp).When I package the app using command line and run the app using that package it's working well and i don't get any error on console. But when i move my app to desktop or out of the local server, and try to run the app, I get error like this:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. sdk.js:1
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue? I am stuck and can't run soundcloud tracks in my app.

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) error. The default behaviour is to prevent requests like this that originate from a different domain. So you need to specifically allow it. If you are installing on a device with PhoneGap you should include this in your config.xml file:

```
<access origin="http://connect.soundcloud.com*"/>
```

If you are hosting it on a server then you should enable CORS, read this website for information: http://enable-cors.org/

Also you may have to use the full URL when getting tracks from SoundCloud:

```
SC.get('https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/', { genres: query, bpm: { from: 150 }, filter: 'streamable' },
function(tracks){
 //...
});
```

instead of:

```
SC.get('/tracks/', { genres: query, bpm: { from: 150 }, filter: 'streamable' },
function(tracks){
 //...
});
```

If you run into any more problems you might find the answer here: http://www.joshmorony.com/final-converting-a-native-android-app-to-sencha-touch-part-5/ I blogged about my experience building an app with Sencha Touch that uses SoundCloud.

Comment: ok i'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks a lot josh, i appreciate it.